# "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at codefolder\modules\user\user.module:1)"

Tags: 6, sessions

i am using drupal 6, mysql 5.5 on apache 2.2 it is working fine.
but when i migrated my code on xampp1.7.3(contain apache2.2 and mysql 5.5).
it gives issue and error.

> warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at codefolder\modules\user\user.module:1) in codefolder\includes\session.inc on line 99.
>   warning: session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate session id - headers already sent in codefolder\includes\session.inc on line 102.
>    Blockquote

and after login pages containing urls like localhost/node/55 shows white pages. while without login it works fine.
while searching on google i found this issue might be due to header but i haven't used any header redirect in my  .tpl.php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was issue due to verision of XAMPP.
Don't know why but on one friend suggestion I started using XAMPP 1.7.4, and it resolved error, previously i have used XAMPP 1.8.3 and then XAMPP 1.7.3.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you don't have any ending php tags at the end of your php files. Sometimes whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) will sneak in at the end of the file after the tag and cause php go into html mode and send the headers too early.

Comment: i haven't modified session.inc and user.module. and there is no any whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines). though it is working fine on linux with Xampp. on my local i have Windows and Xampp.

Comment: So do you have any code, like a module, of your own there? If you do, does Drupal run OK with your module disabled?

Comment: i have created more them 20custom modules as this is an enterprise application.

Comment: i was using xampp's latest verision, and then used 1.7.3 as i needed apache 2.2,
but one friend suggested to use Xampp 1.7.4
and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly Found in php bust as @Kari Kaariainen said do it and another thing is that go to the top of that page and make sure there is no white space.